# React NextJS app, installed webpack, then removed it: Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeOutputFileSystem'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

While trying to figure out how to create and use ENV secrets with a frontend only ReactJS / NextJS app I broke my app installing webpack.

https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/805

After I `npm install webpack` I realized that I should not install webpack myself since that is already handled by NextJS.

So I removed my node_modules folder, removed webpack from my package.json, but now when I try to run my app with: `npm run dev` I get the following error:

```
moonholdings.io [actionsReducers●] % npm run dev

> moon.holdings@2.0.0 dev /Users/leongaban/projects/Futuratum/moonholdings.io
> next -p 7777

{ Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeOutputFileSystem'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/leongaban/projects/Futuratum/moonholdings.io/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/fs.js:7:30)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Thoughts on why this would be happening?

**My next.config.js**

```
const { PHASE_PRODUCTION_SERVER } =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? {}
    : !process.env.NOW_REGION
      ? require('next/constants')
      : require('next-server/constants');

module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  if (phase === PHASE_PRODUCTION_SERVER) {
    // Config used to run in production.
    return {};
  }

  // ✅ Put the require call here.
  const withTypescript = require('@zeit/next-typescript');
  const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-sass');

  return withTypescript(withCSS());
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "moon.holdings",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Moon Holdings, your cryptocurrency portfolio.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next -p 7777",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 8000",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watch --no-cache",
    "test-win": "SET NODE_ENV=test&& jest --watch",
    "heroku-postbuild": "next build"
  },
  "author": "Futuratum",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-typescript": "^1.1.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.16",
    "apollo-client": "^2.4.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "decko": "^1.2.0",
    "downshift": "^2.2.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "next-with-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-adopt": "^0.6.0",
    "react-apollo": "^2.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^3.4.9",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4",
    "waait": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.15",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
    "@types/next": "^7.0.6",
    "@types/ramda": "^0.25.49",
    "@types/react": "^16.7.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/zeit__next-typescript": "^0.1.1",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-sass-vars": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.7.1",
    "casual": "^1.5.19",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-transform-graphql": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/.next/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "transform": {
      ".*": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.ts?$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts",
      "tsx"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/components/",
      "<rootDir>/pages/",
      "<rootDir>/shared/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: did you run `npm install` again after deleting the `node_modules` folder and deleting `webpack` from your package.json ?

Comment: @axm__ yes I did, I just found the right fix for this tho, posting now...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the answer in the following trend here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2131#issuecomment-383017060

```
rm -R node_modules
rm package-lock.json #(this should be removed)
npm cache verify
npm install
```

Now my `npm run dev` works again!